# can I execute a particular block of code inside a method via thread

Tags: java, multithreading

can I execute a particular block of code inside a method via thread. As for example

```
Class A{
    public void execute(){

    /* some code where threading is not required*/
    /* block of code which need to execute via thread */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class A {
    public void execute() {

        /* some code where threading is not required*/

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                /* block of code which need to execute via thread */
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yup all you have to do is implement runnable, then call that meathod inside of run()